# Complex roots of unity in a matrix

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

> Let $\omega $ be a complex cube root of unity with $\omega \ne 1 $ and $P=[p_{ij}]$ be a $n \times n $ matrix with $p_{ij}=\omega^{i+j}$ . Then $P^2 \ne0$ when $n=$
>
> (A) 57
>
> (B) 55
>
> (C) 58
>
> (D) 56

Official answer is $B,C,D$. Considering the values are greater than $50$ if we see the answer, based on my assumption, the value of $n$ is not a multiple of $3$.

We need to find the square matrix whose square is not equal to zero matrix.
How do we find the value of $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P^2$=$\begin{bmatrix}w^2 &w^3 &w^4& .&.&.\\
  w^3 \\
w^4 \\
.\\
.\end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix}w^2 &w^3 &w^4& .&.&.\\
  w^3 \\
w^4 \\
.\\
.\end{bmatrix}$
=$\begin{bmatrix}w^4+w^6+w^8+...& .&.&.\\
  . \\
. \\
.\\
.\end{bmatrix}$
=$\begin{bmatrix}w+1+w^2+...& .&.&.\\
  . \\
. \\
.\\
.\end{bmatrix}$=$\begin{bmatrix}0+...& .&.&.\\
  . \\
. \\
.\\
.\end{bmatrix}$ 
 We deduce that $n$ should not be a multiple of $3$. Doubt?